# Chrome v71 anchor tag scope chain references inner img tag's scope

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scope

After updating to Chrome v71, I've found a strange behavior regarding a scope of an anchor tag that has an img tag inside such as this:

```
<a href="#none" onclick="debugger;complete();">
  <img src="https://clickmeuk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/click-me-logo2x.png"/>
</a>
...
function complete() {
   alert("haha");
}
```

On Chrome until v71 and other browsers, clicking the img will trigger onclick event and an alert is shown. But since the latest update, same code results in invoking an error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: complete is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:6)
```

This happens because on Chrome v71, the scope of onclick of the anchor tag reaches img tag scope **before** it reaches global scope, hence referencing the `complete` field of img node instead of `complete()` function. This is reproducible in this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQoqVa).

The `<img>` is a child node of `<a>`, so when onclick is triggered, referencing scope of `<img>` seems strange. Of course, you can fix it by simply changing the name of the function to something other than `complete`. But I don't know what could've caused the change. Chrome v70 or Explorer or Safari works as expected. Could this be a bug? Or did I miss some update which isn't yet implemented by other browsers?

Comment: I remember seeing something like this before (months ago, before Chrome 71, maybe Chrome 65 or something), an `onclick` *attribute* has an implicit `with(this)`, or something of the sort, where `this` references the element, very confusing (another reason to avoid inline handlers)

Comment: Well, it seems you've done your duty at analyzing the issue and finding a solution. What do you expect from SO community as an answer? "Yes that's a bug"? "Nope it's made on purpose"? This question would be better suited to a chromium's issue, where the ones that did these changes will be able to tell for sure. (Ps: still repro in 73)

Comment: @Kaiido My solution was more of a workaround, I wanted to know the underlying issue that caused the change in scope interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a [bisect](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) over your test case reveals that the change was made in [this ChangeLog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/7e3da6dc3d7cd7eb8a55ef301026fe1ab737f814..56dd83c9005f68d55ddbf85c551759526b4e37c).

From this list of commits, [*Create new EventHandler and base class for EventListener/EventHandler* by Yuki Yamada](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/1b2f95835607dbb9c6021df8893fb18f4c7aee9e) seems to be the most plausible cause of change of behavior in this area.

Reading the commit description and the linked crbugs [664676](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664676) & [759461](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=759461), nothing lets think this is an intended change.

Chrome had issues with the EventTarget's Realm they were using, and the specs did change a bit, but from what I read, I can't see anything that would make the observed behavior the expected one, nor is this behavior even referenced.

So, from here, this all sounds like a bug yes. Feel free to open a new issue on [chromium's board](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/), in *Blink > Binding* component.

You might want to let them know the [ChangeLog URL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/7e3da6dc3d7cd7eb8a55ef301026fe1ab737f814..56dd83c9005f68d55ddbf85c551759526b4e37c) that the bisect shown. They will be able to tell you if it was really intended or not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how to tackle regression bugs on Chromium! It's a first I had to deal with it. I'll send a bug report as well.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=913310#c1 Patch is applied in Canary and future version as well.